# How to remove local storage value only on initial loads of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a situation where I have some values in stored local storage. I want to clear those values when the page loads for the first time. But, after that, if I want to set those values again,I should be able to do this and page refresh shouldn't remove this as well. So. the question is: are there any ways of doing something only on initial loads of the component and don't do anything afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `count` variable and when `react` app runs for the first time `useEffect` will remove required items from `localstorage` and will set `count` to `1` in localstorage and then everytime `component` re-renders it will check in `localstorage` if count is 1 if it is 1 then it won't remove item from `localstorage`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(localStorage.getItem('count') !== '1') {
    localStorage.removeItem('val')
    localStorage.setItem('count', '1')
  }
  set()
}, [])

const set = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('val', 'skndkj')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the typical use of `sessionStorage`. It works the same way as `localStroage`, but it will be clear after users closes browsers. However, between page reloads, it is preserved.

You can use it like this:

```js
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
const data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: I need to store my values to local storage because session storage values  doesn't preserve in multi tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a date as an extra value to your data. Then, just check if the date is the current date or not. if not the current date, it will clear your local storage.